# Python/Pandas getting all possible combinations with one restriction

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, combinatorics

Goal - I have 50 records total and need to find all of the possible combinations of 6 players with the salary <= 50,000 and >= 48,000.

The code below will work if I only use about 20 records but I keep hitting memory errors when trying to apply it to all 50 records. I'm looking for a way to optimize my code to either only accept combinations under 50k without looping like I am if possible.

Example Data (currently have 50 records total)-

```
    ID          Salary
0   11282489    11000
1   11282517    10800
2   11282479    10700
3   11282521    10200
4   11282483    10100
5   11282481    10000
```

Current code -

```
comb = combinations(data['ID'], 6) 
comb_list = list(comb)
df_list = []
for i in comb_list:
    i = list(i)
    if data.loc[data['ID'].isin(i)]['Salary'].sum() <= 50000 and data.loc[data['ID'].isin(i)]['Salary'].sum() >= 48000:
        df_list.append(data.loc[data['ID'].isin(i)])

    counter +=1
```

The 'comb_list' is currently ending up at about 15M combinations which is the main problem. Is there a better way to apply the salary filter than I'm currently doing?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you filter by salary range first, then call `combinations` on the filtered result?

Comment: The salary total is the sum of the 6 record combinations so I don't think theres a way to really filter got for that.

Comment: my mistake. I should read more carefully!

Comment: I bet there's a smart way to do this by sorting the IDs by Salary first and ignoring unnecessary combinations. But it's a cool problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly avoid the loop.

Find all of the combinations, map their IDs to the salary and then calculate the sum for every combination. Then just subset to those combinations where the salary is between 48,000 and 50,000

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(1,51,1),
                   'Salary': np.random.randint(7000,12000,50)})
# ID to Salary dictionary
d = df.set_index('ID').Salary.to_dict()
```

#### Code

```
n = 6  # length of combination tuples

# Create df of people and their salary
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(df.ID, n)), 
                   columns=['p'+str(i) for i in np.arange(1,n+1,1)])
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df2.replace(d).add_suffix('_salary')], axis=1)

# Subset to those within the range you care about
df2[df2[[col for col in df2.columns if '_salary' in col]].sum(1).between(48000,50000)]
```

#### Output

```
        p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p1_salary  p2_salary  p3_salary  p4_salary  p5_salary  p6_salary
48465    1   2   6  10  19  32      10582      10454       7096       7111       7039       7588
48481    1   2   6  10  19  48      10582      10454       7096       7111       7039       7371
209845   1   3   5   6   9  10      10582       8346       8593       7096       7942       7111
209854   1   3   5   6   9  19      10582       8346       8593       7096       7942       7039
209883   1   3   5   6   9  48      10582       8346       8593       7096       7942       7371
...
```

(There are 188,531 such combinations). There are bound to be even more efficient solutions.